# How to open .mxd file in QGIS 2.6.1

Tags: qgis

I have few files created with ArcGIS in .mxd format.

Now I dont have ArcGIS and want to work with QGIS along with these .mxd file formats.

How can I solve this problem (along with each step to be taken)?

Comment: This tool seem  to export from arcgis to a .qgs file, they will be of no use for people who cant use arcgis

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know there is no way to open .mxd (a proprietary Esri format) with QGIS.

Anyway if you only have the .mxd you wont be able to do much with it (even using ArcGIS) as these files do not contain any data (only reference to datasource, styling info, layout, ...).

On the other hand if you have the associated data you could use these in QGIS and may be able to reproduce the original MXD (but you need to know what it is supposed to look like)